# CarPlay MFI resources

Tags: usb, mfi, carplay

Does anyone know where MFI documentation or a place to ask questions can be found specific to CarPlay?

I’m a newer developer and working on a hardware accessory that works with CarPlay, but getting the runaround on resources. I know the MFI program can be tough to get insight into, but hoping someone here might have an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's MFi program is something that requires a bit of work to apply for and be accepted. Apple, from outward appearances, is interested in those that have a bonafide need for the information which is provided under a non-disclosure agreement.

You will need to have a company such as a DBA, LLC, or S Corp. That company will need to have a credit rating with Dun & Bradstreet. (which implies filing with the state, incorporation paperwork, etc.)

Long story short, MFi appears to not be open to hobbyists.

Here is the skinny for signing up for the MFi Program:
https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

and in particular the enrollment portal:
https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/enroll.action

and last but definitely not least the FAQs which I would recommend reading from top to bottom:
https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action