# CarPlay with Apple Enterprise Developer Program

Tags: ios, apple-developer, carplay

I was considering developing an in-house iOS application that supports CarPlay. However the problem is that when I am trying to apply for CarPlay entitlement with this link: https://developer.apple.com/contact/carplay/ on my enterprise account it gives me an information that I need to be a member of Apple Developer Program.

So I understand that as a member of Apple Enterprise Developer Program I am not able to develop for CarPlay?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971137/does-ios-enterprise-program-allow-to-add-entitlements-to-provisioning-profiles) (rather old) answer says that you can't use special entitlements with enterprise builds.  I don't think anything has changed. You might need to ask Apple directly through developer support

Comment: You need MFi program, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857552/carplay-mfi-resources.

Answer (score -1):

1 . in-house iOS application for you need to purchase enterprise developer account.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/($299)

Comment: Cool, but that does not answer my question. I am member of Enterprise program, but I cannot apply for CarPlay entitlement.